# Create infinite loop with css

Tags: html, css, image, loops, infinite-loop

I have an image of waves that takes about the bottom third of the screen(not the background image) that I want to run on an infinite loop from right to the left but using css. I have tried different things but so far have been unable to make it work.

I have defined the img src on the HTML, but if needed i can do it on the css file.

Any help or suggestions on how to do it are appreciated.

CSS

```
body {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 700px;
    background-image: url("./cave.jpg");
    background-size: 700px 505px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
}

.waves {
    height: 380px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    animation: animatedImage 20s linear infinite;
}

    @keyframes animatedImage {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: 100% 0;}
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Escape the Cave</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jogo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
     <img class="waves" src="./ondas.png">

      </div>
    <script src="jogo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An `<img />` element's image is not the same thing as a `background-image` and you cannot animate an `<img />` element the same way you can with CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

I moved class "waves" on div in which image is putted, because it's easier to operate.
Here's CSS

```
body {
border: 2px solid black;
width: 700px;
background-image: url("./cave.jpg");
background-size: 700px 505px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px 10px;
}

.waves {
height: 380px;
width: 700px;
position: relative;
top: -300px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
animation: animatedImage 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedImage {
    0% { left: 0;}
    50%{ left : 100%;}
    100%{ left: 0;}
}



HTML

<div class="waves">
 <img  src="https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_2tugi/styles/communityIcon_7yzrvmem0wi31.png">
</div>
```